# apache2 virtual host sub domain migration

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

electronicarchitect.com is the old domain,
i am looking to replace with rrh.com

What i want:
electronicarchitect.com : rrh.com
portal.electronicarchitect.com : portal.rrh.com

currently, when i go to portal.rrh.com, for some reason i takes me to the same location as rrh.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName electronicarchitect.com
            ServerAlias www.electronicarchitect.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/electronicarchitect.com

            ErrorLog /etc/apache2/logs/electronicarchitect.com/error.log

            # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.
            LogLevel warn

            <Directory /var/www/electronicarchitect.com>
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>

            CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/electronicarchitect.com/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName portal.electronicarchitect.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/portal.electronicarchitect.com

            ErrorLog /etc/apache2/logs/portal.electronicarchitect.com/error.log

            # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.
            LogLevel warn

            <Directory /var/www/portal.electronicarchitect.com>
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>

            #alias /php-myadmin/ "/var/www/portal.electronicarchitect.com/php-myadmin/"
            #<Directory "/var/www/portal.electronicarchitect.com/php-myadmin">
            #        AllowOverride All
            #        Options FollowSymlinks
            #        Order allow,deny
            #        Allow from all
            #        DirectoryIndex index.php
            #</Directory>

            CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/portal.electronicarchitect.com/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>


    __
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.rrh.com
    ServerAlias rrh.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@rrh.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/electronicarchitect.com/

    <Directory /var/www/electronicarchitect.com/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/electronicarchitect.com.error.log

    #Possible Values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    #alert, emerg.
    LogLevel alert

    ServerSignature On
    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName portal.rrh.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@rrh.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/portal.electronicarchitect.com/

    <Directory /var/www/portal.electronicarchitect.com/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/rrh.error.log

    #Possible Values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    #alert, emerg.
    LogLevel alert

    ServerSignature On
    </VirtualHost>
```

sorry for the poor formatting, stackoverflow was giving issues when creating this post.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up your sub CNAME?

The CNAME record point to subdomain:

portal.electronicarchitect.com (in this case)

Keep in mind DNS can take a while to update/proliferate.

Set up Apache.
Add sub to /etc/apache2/sites-available (you did this already, including for reference for others.)

sub:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
        ServerName subDomainName.myDomain.com    
            <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
            </Proxy>    
            <Location />
                ProxyPass http://192.168.1.101/
                ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.101/
            </Location>    
</VirtualHost>
```